# Why do I keep getting Null?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=1985428', (error, response, html) => {
    if(!error && response.statusCode ==200){
        //console.log(html);
        const $ = cheerio.load(html); 
        
        const profTopComment = $('.Comments__StyledComments-dzzyvm-0 dvnRbr');
        
        console.log(profTopComment.html());
    }
});
```

I'm trying to create a chrome extension to scrape data from RatemyProffessor but when trying to scrape the most meaningful comment from the url above, I keep getting null, any help would be awesome!

When I say "getting Null" I mean console.log(profTopComment.html()) is giving me null in the terminal.

I am trying to scrape Most Helpful Rating.

Comment: Could be the selector is wrong, or the element doesn't exist yet

Comment: @charlietfl I don't believe I have the wrong selector, but I am new to web scraping. Here's the link to the page i'm trying to scrape, I am trying to scrape "MOST HELPFUL RATING": [link] (https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=1985428)

Comment: @charlietfl Could you elaborate on what you mean by "the element doesn't exist yet"?

Comment: Possibly it is inserted using javascript after the page loads and isn't there at the time you run your code. Try adding a setTimeout and see if that does any good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `'.Comments__StyledComments-dzzyvm-0.dvnRbr'` the second `"."` is needed
  to look for a `<div></div>` element with `two` different classes on it
- Basically just change `'.Comments__StyledComments-dzzyvm-0 dvnRbr'` to `'.Comments__StyledComments-dzzyvm-0.dvnRbr'` in your code.

Example:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

async function testFunc() {
  const result = await 
  axios.get('https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=1985428');
  const $ = cheerio.load(result.data);
  const profTopComment = $('.Comments__StyledComments-dzzyvm-0.dvnRbr');
  console.log(profTopComment.html());
}
testFunc();
```

Comment: Do explain why the code you posted is supposed to solve the problem stated. Code, on its own, is not that helpful.

Comment: (The embedded comment should be elevated to an explanation in regular text before or after your code example. *Explain* as well as show).